# Mostrar Archivos de una carpeta "x" del servidor en asp.net MVC 5 C# al llamarla por nombre de carpeta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, servidor

Necesito cargar una vista de una tabla en un Proyecto Asp.net MVC 5 C#
Donde se muestre los archivos que existen en un servidor pero solo necesito
mostrar la carpeta que tenga la ID = X (se la pasaria por string) al action, alguna idea?

Es decir, existen mas de 1000 carpetas en el servidor con ID diferentes, lo que necesito es que me muestre todos los archivos que existen en la carpeta cuando lo llamo con un id, ejemplo con la id = 2

la tabla quedaria asi en la vista web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me va a mostrar todos los archigos con el nombre de la carpeta "2",
de igual forma si lo llamo con la ID = 3, ID = 4, Debería mostrarme los
archivos según el nombre de la carpeta.

he estado leyendo sobre

Answer (score 1):

En tu HomeController de tu ASP MVC podrías poner el siguiente codigo:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string clientId="defaultId")
    {
        ViewBag.clientId = clientId;
        var pathCarpeta = System.IO.Path.Combine("E:\\DemoRaiz\\", clientId);

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathCarpeta))
        {
            var listaArchivos = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(pathCarpeta);
            
            ViewBag.listaArchivos = listaArchivos;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.listaArchivos = new string[0];
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Y del lado del Index.cshtml algo como esto:

```html
<div class="row">
    <br />
    <div>
       Cliente ID:  @ViewBag.clientId
    </div>
    <br />
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Documento</th>
                <th>Link</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @{string[] listaArchivos = ViewBag.listaArchivos; }
        @for (int i = 0; i < listaArchivos.Length; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@System.IO.Path.GetFileName(listaArchivos[i])</td>
                <td><a href="@listaArchivos[i]">Servidor/@System.IO.Path.GetFileName(listaArchivos[i])</a></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

espero te funcione, saludos!

Comment: funciona excelente! solo la ultima consulta, los links no descargan el documento, de hecho a la hora de mostrar los datos muestra la direccion correcta del documento pero al darle clic no hace nada, es decir, no se descarga el documento, sabes porque puede ser?

Comment: Ya lo tengo, lo hice con un FileResult pero sin tu ayuda no hubiese poddido,  muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si, tambien puedes resolverlo con archivos en base64, saludos!